# How to correctly create a PyTorch Tensor from a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: pandas, pytorch, dataframe, gradient

I have loaded my data into a Pandas DataFrame, and performed some pre-processing, and then I need to convert it into a PyTorch Tensor for training as my features data.

Obviously, This new tensor do **NOT** need auto-gradient with it, because it is only source data.

I convert the df into a tensor like follows:

```
features = torch.tensor( data = df.iloc[:, 1:cols].values, requires_grad = False )
```

I dare **NOT** use `torch.from_numpy()`, as that the tensor will share the storing space with the source numpy.ndarray according to the [PyTorch's docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.from_numpy.html#torch.from_numpy).

Not only the source ndarray is a temporary obj, but also the original DataFrame will be released before training, because it is huge.

Further more, I'm worrying about the training performance, so I want to my feature data is really stored in a Tensor, not in some form of 'View', or sharing space with ndarray/df.

I'm confused by the PyTorch's docs, since it says that `from_numpy` will sharing space, and that `torch.Tensor.clone()` will carry gradient, and if `detach()` be used, one more copying will occur.

I just need to create a neat Tensor owning data, without gradient, and at best, with less data copying op.

Is my method correct? or is there any better way?